# Qt QMediaPlayer кэш для данных из сети

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

У меня есть список ссылок на треки которые я хочу проигрывать через `QMediaPlayer`.
Я хочу что бы `QMediaPlayer` кэшировал файлы которые уже были скачены, но я не смог найти способа использовать свой объект `QNetworkAccessManager` с `QNetworkDiskCache`.
Как сделать так что бы `QMediaPlayer` кэшировал файлы загруженные из сети?

Comment: Я не знаю, умеет ли `QMediaPlayer` кешировать, но есть вариант самому написать с помощью `QCache`.И уже перед загрузкой проверять его.

Comment: @MrBin Я думал реализовать свою версию плейлиста для `QMediaPlayer` в которой уже будет использовать QNAM с кэшированием. Но перед этим решил поискать готовое решение, но не смог его найти и написал сюда.

Comment: Напишите тогда ответ. На будущее, вдруг кому понадобиться.